# How to convert between various ItemSize/ImageSize units?

Tags: front-end, units, conversion

How can one convert between the implicit units used by `Grid` (**ems** and **line height** for horizontal and vertical dimensions) and **printers points** (in `GraphicsGrid` and `Graphics`)?

```
Grid[{{"sample", "text"}}, Frame -> All, 
 ItemSize -> {{4, 7}, Automatic}]

Row@{Framed["sample", ImageSize -> 60, FrameMargins -> 0], 
  Framed["sample", ImageSize -> 100, FrameMargins -> 0]}

GraphicsGrid[{{"sample", "text"}}, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> 7]

GraphicsGrid[{{Item["sample", ItemSize -> 4], 
   Item["text", ItemSize -> 7]}}, Frame -> All(*,ImageSize->160*)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The last two examples show that, while the [documentation of `ItemSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ItemSize.html) states that "In GraphicsGrid, *w* and *h* are both measured in absolute printer's points", `ItemSize` cannot be used as an option for `GraphicsGrid` and it doesn't do anything as an option for an internal object wrapped in `Item`.

**Realistic example**

Here is a particular problem, that presents the issue of different units in the same object. The task is to automatically scroll a `Pane` to a certain line in a dataset.
**Updated**: Improved code according to Heike, to keep the line in focus at the top.

```
data = Range@200;
lineHeight = 1.5;
conversion = 14; (* magic number *)
paneHeight = 120;

update[n_] := (scrollToThis = n; 
   pos = (scrollToThis - 1)*lineHeight*conversion);
update@1;

Row@{Slider[Dynamic[scrollToThis, (update@#) &], {1, Length@data, 1}],
   "  line: ", Dynamic@scrollToThis, "   at position: ", Dynamic@pos}
Dynamic[Framed[
  Pane[Grid[List /@ data, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {5, lineHeight}, 
    Background -> {White, {scrollToThis -> Red}}],
   ImageSize -> {100, paneHeight}, Scrollbars -> {False, True}, 
   ScrollPosition -> {0, pos}, ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0], 
  ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0], 
 TrackedSymbols :> {scrollToThis, pos}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Question**

Is there a way to convert between different units (**ems** / **lineheight** <--> **printers points**) in a foolproof way?

Comment: For reference I need a "magic number" of `22.77` on my machine.

Comment: Regarding your example, if `ScrollPosition` only accepts pixel measurements as briefly skimming the help suggests I don't see how this can be done reliably.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I would assume that lineheight depends on actual screen size/resolution/other factors, which are accessible in _Mathematica_, though I don't want to go through discovering the relationship if anyone else has already done this.

Comment: I think it's just too complicated.  I expect that it varies with version and platform.

Comment: I get a magic number of 10. Note that the scroll position refers to the pixel that should appear at the top left corner of the pane, so the definition of `pos` should be something like `pos = (scrollToThis-1/2)*lineHeight*conversion+ paneHeight/2` for some value of conversion if you want the highlighted cell to appear in the middle for any value of `scrollToThis`.

Comment: @Heike: I've utilized your idea, and now a magic number of `14` keeps the focus line exactly at the top: any other `conversion` number causes the focus line to lag behind or go faster than necessary.

Comment: @IstvánZachar 14 works for me as well for the values given, but if I change `lineHeight` in your latest code, the cells are shifted again. This is probably due to the fact that the height of the cells in the grid is determined by the setting for `ItemSize` plus the setting for `Spacings`. The latter is set to `Automatic` by default so for full control you should set that to some absolute value as well (I've set it to `{0,0}` in my solution below).

Comment: wikipedia says 1 em is always whatever the point setting is. In Mma I'd interpret that as meaning if the base style is 12 then 1 em is 12. If the base style is 18 then 1 em is 18 -- assuming it has been implemented that way in Mma. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really the done thing to answer a question you've set a bounty on, but here is an explanation of why Mike's answer isn't quite right. The first point to note is that item sizes include the width of frames, so one needs to allow for the thickness of the frames in the `ImageSize` option for the second grid (thus the `+2` in the option since `FrameStyle` has a setting including `AbsoluteThickness[1]` and you need to count both sides.)

It's also necessary to ensure `ContentPadding` is `False`. This affects placement of the text in the grid cell.

Finally, `Row` doesn't take the  `Spacings` option while `Grid` does. In these circumstances it helps to used `Grid` for both cases. Notice I've used the `Offset` specification of spacing, which only counts the spacing excluding frames and borders.

```
Overlay[{Grid[{{"Sample", "Text"}}, Frame -> All, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Red], 
   Spacings -> {Offset[0], 0}, ItemSize -> itemSize, 
   Alignment -> {Left, Center}], 
  Grid[{{Framed["Sample", 
      ImageSize ->  2 + Dynamic[
         itemSize*{CurrentValue["FontMWidth"], 
           CurrentValue["FontLineHeight"]}], FrameMargins -> 0, 
      BaseStyle -> Red, 
      FrameStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Blue], 
      ContentPadding -> False], 
     Framed["Text", 
      ImageSize -> 
       Dynamic[{2, 2} + 
         itemSize*{CurrentValue["FontMWidth"], 
           CurrentValue["FontLineHeight"]}], FrameMargins -> 0, 
      BaseStyle -> Red, 
      FrameStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Blue], 
      ContentPadding -> False]}}, Spacings -> {Offset[0], 0}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I would gladly give the bounty to you, if it would be possible.

Comment: alas, that's not allowed, since it was mine :)

Answer (score 8):

You can access many different font characteristics via CurrentValue. Here is an approximation to convert between ItemSize and ImageSize:

```
itemSize = {10, 10};
Overlay[{
  Grid[
     {{"Sample", "Text"}}, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {0, 0}, 
     ItemSize -> itemSize, Alignment -> {Left, Center}],      
  Row[{
     Framed["Sample",  ImageSize -> 
         Dynamic[itemSize*{CurrentValue["FontMWidth"], 
         CurrentValue["FontLineHeight"]}], 
         FrameMargins -> 0, FrameStyle -> Blue],
     Framed["Text", ImageSize -> 
         Dynamic[itemSize*{CurrentValue["FontMWidth"], 
         CurrentValue["FontLineHeight"]}], 
         FrameMargins -> 0, FrameStyle -> Blue]}]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: The output looks totally different on my computer (Win7-64, MMA 8.04). The test words don't overlap at all and the boxes are shifted. However, this is only so the first time I execute this code, but if I run it a second time it looks like your picture. Strange.

Comment: Same thing on Mac 10.8, MMA 8.04, but things don't line back up when I run it a second time.

Comment: @Mike you had quite a bit of the answer but it needs some fixing up, for example using some of the material in my answer. If you can do this in the next 12 hours I can award the bounty. Otherwise it will expire.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to work on my system at least, but as Mr.Wizard said it might be system dependent

```
lineHeight = 1.5;
conversion = 10;(*magic number*)
scrollToThis = 80;
paneHeight = 200;

pos = (scrollToThis - 1/2)*lineHeight*conversion - paneHeight/2;  
Framed[ 
  Pane[
    Grid[List /@ data, Frame -> All, 
      ItemSize -> {5, lineHeight}, 
      Background -> {White, {scrollToThis -> Red}}, Spacings -> {0, 0}], 
    ImageSize -> {100, paneHeight}, Scrollbars -> {False, True}, 
    ScrollPosition -> {0, pos}, ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0], 
  ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0]
```

With these settings the highlighted cell always appears in the middle of the `Pane` independent of the values of `scrollToThis`, `paneHeight`, and `lineHeight` (provided `lineHeight>1`).

Alternatively, you could wrap each cell in the Grid in a Pane with a fixed height and use that to scroll to the right position:

```
scrollToThis = 80;
cellHeight = 20;
margins = 1;
width = 120;
paneHeight = 200;

gr = Grid[List[Pane[#, {width - 20, cellHeight},
       Alignment -> {Center, Center}, ImageMargins -> margins]] & /@ 
    data, 
   Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
   Spacings -> {0, 0}, Alignment -> {Center, Center},
   Background -> {White, {scrollToThis -> Red}}];
pos = (scrollToThis - 1/2)*(cellHeight + 2 margins) - paneHeight/2;

Framed[
 Pane[gr, ImageSize -> {width, paneHeight}, 
  Scrollbars -> {False, True}, ScrollPosition -> {0, pos}, 
  ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0], 
 ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0]
```