# Right aligning a button in a dialog

Tags: gui-construction

What is the best way to right align a button in a dialog window, regardless of the window's `WindowSize`?

Here is a resizable window to test on:

```
CreateDialog[
 Column[{"Here's some text text text text text text text", 
         ChoiceButtons[]}], 
 WindowFrameElements -> {"ResizeArea"}, 
 WindowFrame -> "Normal"]
```

I would like the button to always be right aligned.

Some unsatisfactory solutions I thought of:

- Put the button in an `Item` and right align.  Then the right margin is determined by the `Column` size which can't easily be set in pixels.
- Put the button in a `Panel`, right align it, and set a fixed size on the panel.  Again, the size is determined by the panel size, not the window size.

**Use case:**

Suppose we need to create an alternative to `MessageDialog`.  This new function, `myMessageDialog`, should take the `WindowSize` option, and the created notebook should respond to `SetOptions[nb, WindowSize -> ...]`  The dialog buttons should always be aligned to the right edge of the window regardless of the window size.

Comment: Please explain further the problem with `Item`.  Could you use `Spacer` to set a margin after converting pixels to printer's points?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Try it in the sample dialog I included and resize the window.  The buttons don't keep on the right if you increase the window size, which would be the ideal solution.  Also, as I said, the right margin is determined by the column size, which is difficult to set properly.  `Item` sizes can only be set in ems, not pixels.  I use the `Item` approach in the image uploader's history dialog, and on a Chinese version of Windows, the sizes are all messed up because of the unpredictability of the em width (different system font).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have tried to solve this problem properly many times during the past few months, and never managed to come up with a solution I'm satisfied with, and which is flexible enough to allow resizable windows.

Comment: `Spacer` uses pixels.  An em is the width of the letter M, or something like that ...

Comment: According to the docs: "Spacer[w] displays as a spacer w printer's points wide." -- if `Spacer` works as desired you can use that to set the margin, can you not?  That's one problem down if so.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not really.  A spacer will push the button to the right, but it will not right align them.  I need them aligned to the right edge of the window itself. Pixels and points are pretty much the same for Mma (not sure about changing the dpi setting though).  Also, the [unit size coversion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-convert-between-various-itemsize-imagesize-units) is not really the main issue here ... I just can't believe there's no proper easy way to do this.  `MessageDialog` does it: it always has the button aligned to the right edge of the window.

Comment: I meant something like `Item[Row[{ChoiceButtons[], Spacer[7]}], Alignment -> Right]` -- you said "right margin" so I assume you want something like this?  Also, have you tried using `Dynamic@CurrentValue["WindowSize"]` to set the size of a `Row`/`Grid`/whatever?

Comment: `Dynamic@CurrentValue["WindowSize"]` is an excellent suggestion!  It is possible to use `CreateDialog[..., WindowSize -> Dynamic[sz]]`, but that is very messy, especially because `sz` can't be properly localized with a `DynamicModule`.  Your suggestion to use `CurrentValue` is much better.  Unfortunately I'm not sure how to set the `Grid` size with this as it is specified in `ItemSize` units.  But it's a step forward nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

This is unrefined, but I'll put it up as a proof of concept:

```
CreateDialog[
  Column[{
   Row[{"Here's some text text text text text text text"}, 
     ImageSize -> Dynamic[CurrentValue["WindowSize"] /. {x_, _} :> x - 15]],
   Item[ChoiceButtons[], Alignment -> Right]
   }],
  WindowFrameElements -> {"ResizeArea"}, WindowFrame -> "Normal"
]
```

Comment: Why do you say "unrefined"?  I see nothing clumsy about it.

Comment: @David thanks :-) I didn't test it with anything but this one example so I am not presenting this as a complete solution, just an illustration of a method.