# Grid - problem with ItemSize being ignored

Tags: bugs, grid-layouts, spacing

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.0 or later. Fixed in 13.0.0 or earlier**

---

I have run into another problem with `Grid` today.
An explicitly specified `ItemSize` is being ignored:

```
dot = Graphics[{Pink, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 40];

tab = {{"Type", "Name", \[SpanFromLeft], \[SpanFromLeft], 
    Item[dot, ItemSize -> 2.7], 
    Item["Esculap", 
     Alignment -> 
      Left], \[SpanFromLeft], \[SpanFromLeft]}, {\[SpanFromAbove], 
    "Dia.", "Spec", \[SpanFromLeft], \[SpanFromAbove], 
    Item[8.3 "mm", ItemSize -> {3.5, 2.7}, Alignment -> Right], 
    Item[11, Alignment -> Right], "6.3"}, {Item[dot, ItemSize -> 2.7],
     Item["Flycatcher", 
     Alignment -> Left], \[SpanFromLeft], \[SpanFromLeft], 
    Item[dot, ItemSize -> 2.7], 
    Item["Apus", 
     Alignment -> 
      Left], \[SpanFromLeft], \[SpanFromLeft]}, {\[SpanFromAbove], 
    Item[6.9 "mm", ItemSize -> {3.5, 2.7}, Alignment -> Right], 
    Item[17, Alignment -> Right], "9.8", \[SpanFromAbove], 
    Item[7.8 "mm", ItemSize -> {3.5, 2.7}, Alignment -> Right], 
    Item[8, Alignment -> Right], "6.7"}};

Grid[tab,
 Spacings -> {Automatic, {{0, -1.1}}},
 Alignment -> {Center, Center},
 Dividers -> All
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please note `Item[8.3 "mm", ItemSize -> {3.5, 2.7}, Alignment -> Right]` where a vertical ItemSize is explicitly specified, yet it is ignored in the layout.

If the "Spec" cell is not spanned this does not happen:

```
tab[[2, 4]] = "X";

Grid[tab,
 Spacings -> {Automatic, {{0, -1.1}}},
 Alignment -> {Center, Center},
 Dividers -> All
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

- Is this another bug in `Grid`?
- Is it still present in version 8?
- How can I best work around it?

Comment: I can confirm that the output of your code looks just the same in MMA ver. 8.0.4.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks.  I have only recently tried to set up a nice looking `Grid` with spanned cells and I must say I'm finding it an aggravating experience.

Comment: Is the title misleading? Can you be sure `ItemSize` is causing the problem? Would something like "Grid -- nested spanning causing problem" be better?

Comment: My point is that `ItemSize` is being ignored.  If you leave out `ItemSize` then the bottom (twin) row looks like the top one.  I was trying to keep the title distinct from [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13349/grid-sizing-and-spacing-problems-with-spanning-cells).

Comment: Can it be due to your `Spacings` setting? I find that `Spacings -> {Automatic, {{0}, -1.3}}` gets me a much better layout. You have to cut away a bit of vertical spacing in the last row only, not in all other rows.

Comment: @Sjoerd `Spacings` certainly is part of the picture, but my settings are intentional (at least the way I believe them to work) to get a layout that is not too unlike the target [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13349/grid-sizing-and-spacing-problems-with-spanning-cells).  Yours do not do that.

Comment: Which of those outputs is your target?

Comment: @Sjoerd the TableForm ones, and also [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7c2kT.png) here; I want the two lines of text closely spaced with a nice margin above and below.

Comment: It works fine on my Mathematica 11.3 (Mathematica running in local, Windows 7). In the cloud (Mma version 12) the problem you mention is not present, but there are other problems of the same kind (ItemSize vertical specification ignored).

Answer (score 8):

The usual quick-and-dirty workaround when `ItemSize` does not do what is expected is to wrap contents into an invisible frame. One can use `Framed` with `FrameStyle->None` to hide the frame or `Pane`. In both cases, a magic number is required to convert between line-height of `Grid` and printers points of `Framed`/`Pane` - it is highly platform-specific (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/89)). The simplified example with `Pane`:

```
dot = Graphics[{Pink, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 40];

magic = 10;

tab = {
   {"Type", "Name", \[SpanFromLeft], \[SpanFromLeft], dot, 
    "Esculap", \[SpanFromLeft], \[SpanFromLeft]},
   {\[SpanFromAbove], "Dia.", 
    "Spec", \[SpanFromLeft], \[SpanFromAbove], 8.3 "mm", 
    Pane[11, {Automatic, 2.7*magic}, Alignment -> Center], "6.3"},
   {dot, "Flycatcher", \[SpanFromLeft], \[SpanFromLeft], dot, 
    "Apus", \[SpanFromLeft], \[SpanFromLeft]},
   {\[SpanFromAbove], 6.9 "mm", 17, "9.8", \[SpanFromAbove], 7.8 "mm",
     Item[8, ItemSize -> {Automatic, 2.7}], "6.7"}
   };

Grid[tab, Spacings -> {Automatic, {{0, -1.1}}}, 
 Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can get rid of the overhang (gap with missing dividers) by wrapping `Item` around the cell:

```
Item[Pane[11, {Automatic, 2.7*magic}, Alignment -> Center]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This issue of gaps is only present in version 8. My guess is that as [`ContentPadding -> True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContentPadding.html) was added to `Pane` in version 8 only, in version 7 a different behaviour is the default for padding inside `Pane` that does not introduce these gaps. However, calling the above example with `ContentPadding -> False` in v8 does not remove the gaps contradily to my expectations.

An almost identical result can be obtained if given cell is wrapped in `Framed` (note the horizontal increase in size of the cell):

```
Framed[11, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 2.7*magic}, FrameStyle -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This works somewhat better than the workaround I came up with using `Spacer`. +1

Comment: If going this route it may be somewhat cleaner to use `Pane[11, {All, 2.7 magic}, Alignment -> Center]`

Comment: True that, I forgot about `Pane`. Actually one (being fool enough) could try to reimplement `Grid` by using only `Pane`, `Framed` and similar constructs. This would be a hell of a task getting all the boxes to align to each other...

Comment: My fallback if I cannot wrestle Grid into submission is to construct a `Graphics` object with `Text`, `Inset`, etc.  I'm hoping to avoid that.

Comment: BTW if you look very closely at the example you'll see that the white frame overlaps the divider.  It would be better to use `FrameStyle -> None` I believe.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of it hence the "ugly" qualifier in the text. Should I include your `Pane` solution as well, or you want to post it as your own answer?

Comment: Please feel free to rewrite this answer using Pane; I think it's the logical step.  (I don't see the need to keep `Framed` too, other than perhaps a comment in passing.)

Comment: Done. This post now makes more sense, hopefully would help lots who wrestle hopelessly with the layout engine of `Grid`.

Comment: What input produces the one with [big gaps?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MNo4C.png)  Do you need both `Pane` *and* `Item` in version 8?  It looks fine with only `Pane` for me (v7).

Comment: Yes, `Pane` introduces gaps, and adding an extra `Item[...]` solves this issue. Added some explanation and a guess.

Comment: I tried the above code with ver. 8.0.4 on OS X without the `Item` or `Frame` work-arounds, and I don't see any gaps. Maybe problem is platform specific? Or maybe it only exists in ver. 8.0.x, where `x < 4`?

Comment: @m_goldberg: I use 8.0.4 as well under Win7.

Comment: @IstvánZachar. Looks like a Win 7 problem then, doesn't it?

Comment: @m_goldberg Could be, but I cannot test that at the moment. Will try to close in on this tomorrow with another machine.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a real answer, but here are two work-arounds. I don't have any real expectation that you will like either ;-)

**Work-around 1**

The idea here is that since there are actually two `Spec` values, the lengend should also have two fileds, each telling the viewer what one of each of the parameters represents.

```
dot = Graphics[{Pink, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 40];

tab = {{"Type", "Name", \[SpanFromLeft], \[SpanFromLeft], 
        Item[dot, ItemSize -> 2.7], Item["Esculap", Alignment -> Left],
        \[SpanFromLeft], \[SpanFromLeft]},
       {\[SpanFromAbove], "Dia.", "Spec 1", "Spec 2", \[SpanFromAbove], 
        Item[8.3 "mm", ItemSize -> {3.5, 2.7}, Alignment -> Right], 
        Item[11, Alignment -> Right], "6.3"},
       {Item[dot, ItemSize -> 2.7], Item["Flycatcher", Alignment -> Left],
        \[SpanFromLeft], \[SpanFromLeft], Item[dot, ItemSize -> 2.7], 
        Item["Apus", Alignment -> Left], \[SpanFromLeft], \[SpanFromLeft]},
       {\[SpanFromAbove], Item[6.9 "mm", ItemSize -> {3.5, 2.7},
                                         Alignment -> Right], 
        Item[17, Alignment -> Right], "9.8", \[SpanFromAbove], 
        Item[7.8 "mm", ItemSize -> {3.5, 2.7}, Alignment -> Right], 
        Item[8, Alignment -> Right], "6.7"}};

Grid[tab, Spacings -> {Automatic, {{0, -1.1}}}, 
          Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Dividers -> All]
```

This outputs

[image]

**Work-around 2**

The idea here is that, given there is only one legend slot, all the other sub-tables should have only one corresponding slot. The two values shown in the combined slots should be shown separated by a suitable delimiter.

```
makeStr = (StringJoin @@ ToString /@ {##}) &;

dot = Graphics[{Pink, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 40];

tab = {{"Type", "Name", \[SpanFromLeft], Item[dot, ItemSize -> 2.7], 
        Item["Esculap", Alignment -> Left], \[SpanFromLeft]},
      {\[SpanFromAbove], "Dia.", "Spec", \[SpanFromAbove], 
       Item[8.3 "mm", ItemSize -> {3.5, 2.7}, Alignment -> Right], 
       makeStr[11, ", ", 6.3]},
      {Item[dot, ItemSize -> 2.7], Item["Flycatcher", Alignment -> Left],
       \[SpanFromLeft], Item[dot, ItemSize -> 2.7], 
       Item["Apus", Alignment -> Left], \[SpanFromLeft]},
      {\[SpanFromAbove], Item[6.9 "mm", ItemSize -> {3.5, 2.7},
                                        Alignment -> Right], 
       makeStr[7, ", ", 9.8], \[SpanFromAbove], 
       Item[7.8 "mm", ItemSize -> {3.5, 2.7}, Alignment -> Right], 
       makeStr[8, ", ", 6.7]}};

Grid[tab, Spacings -> {Automatic, {{0, -1.1}}}, 
          Alignment -> {Center, Center}, Dividers -> All]
```

This outputs

[image]

Comment: These are, unsurprisingly, the two options I am aware of.  I'm holding my vote for now as I am hoping for some *other* answer, but it's good that you've documented them.  Incidentally you could use `makeStr = Row@{##} &;`.

Comment: No, I'm not surprised you were aware of these work-arounds, but I felt they should be explicitly put on the table. You _did_ ask for work-arounds.

Comment: Did you actually try your version of `makeStr`? It was the first thing I thought of, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Indeed I did, and it appears to work in version 7 for this example.  How does it fail for you?

Comment: I have figured out what I did wrong. My version, because of bad typing was `makeStr = (Row@{#})&`.

Answer (score 3):

The situation appears to have been fixed in `V13.0.0` or earlier. Grabbing the code from the OP and executing it, gives:

[image: bugfixed]