# Why does list assignment with a packed array result in unpacked values?

Tags: functions, bugs, implementation-details, assignment, packed-arrays

**Bug introduced in 5.2 or earlier and fixed in 10.1.0**

---

This is another question on the design choices in *Mathematica*.  I understand that without direct reply from the developers it may not be possible to give a definitive and exhaustive answer to "why" questions but such topics have often been fruitful.

---

Why does list assignment of the form `{a, b, c} = tensor` where `tensor` is packed result in *unpacked* values for `a`, `b`, and `c`?

To illustrate:

```
packedQ = Developer`PackedArrayQ;

tensor = RandomReal[99, {3, 5, 7}];

tensor // packedQ
```

> True

```
{a, b, c} = tensor;

packedQ /@ {a, b, c}
```

> {False, False, False}

It is possible to make the assignments without unpacking the sub-arrays of `tensor` by manually unpacking the outer list using `Apply`:

```
{a, b, c} = List @@ tensor;

packedQ /@ {a, b, c}
```

> {True, True, True}

#### Why doesn't `Set` operate like this by default?

That is, why doesn't `Set` only unpack the right-hand-side as far as necessary, to the level of the left-hand-side?

Comment: Your question raises another in my mind: since `tensor` already has the head `List`, why does `List @@ tensor` have any effect on `Set` at all, considering it's evaluated before `Set` even sees it?

Comment: @m_goldberg Because `Apply` does unpack the top level of the packed array. It does it always, even if the head to be applied is also a `List`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin. So, although it's not his main point, one thing Mr.Wizard is telling us is that when `Set` is given tensor with its top-level unpacked, the lower levels will not be disturbed.

Comment: @m_goldberg Yes, that is what I tried to express that with the final example given.  Another way to look at this problem is that apparently when `Set` gets a packed array on the RHS and a list on the LHS, it fully unpacks the RHS rather that only unpacking it to the level of the LHS.  This seems like an unfortunate choice, but I have often learned that there are good reasons for such choices once I asked about them.

Comment: I had thought @m_goldberg's question was why is `Apply` designed that way.  That `Apply` always unpacks the first level is not an explanation why it does it when it's unnecessary.  I would think that it's because `List @@ List[..]` is not important enough to make a special case.  Or it's so that `{a, b, c} = List @@ tensor` is a workaround for `Set`'s behavior.  Or something else like that.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I would agree that the special case of `List` was probably considered not important. In fact, the only reason one would want to do `List @@ packed` would be if one wants to unpack one level. It also seems to be the only way to do this (i.e. using `Apply`), if one wants to only unpack one level.

Comment: @Leonid I believe you could also use `#& /@ packed`, and even other functions such as `Outer`, though inelegantly: `Outer[# &, packed, {1}, 1][[All, 1]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `Map` only unpacked because the length of the list was smaller than "MapCompileLength" setting. And `Outer` is rather inelegant, I agree.

Comment: @Leonid I see from these comments that a year ago I was unaware that this also unpacks one level: `/. h_@x__ :> h@x`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, I think this was kind of easy to guess, since the pattern matcher has no way to not unpack for this particular rule.

Comment: Just a small comment on an old question. Since packed arrays were only introduced in version 5.0, I would think that if it exists in 5.2 it probably was a simple omission in the (AIUI, involved) operation of grafting packed arrays into the language in the first place. I am not quite sure what this meant about its "bug-ness" before the report was filed.

Comment: @Oleksandr Good point.  I was only going off Tali's  *"I've filed a bug for this"* but perhaps it is more of a limitation than a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks Mr.Wizard. I've filed a bug for this, #288440 if you have future correspondence with people inside the company about it...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @m_goldberg Do you think it is reasonable to make an exception for the developers of *Mathematica*?  Given at least some implied authority here this *is* a form of answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Perhaps the issue you bring up should be discussed in Meta. Personally, I'd be happy with this being treated as an exception granted by the moderators  should that be the moderator position.

Comment: @m_goldberg, since Taliesin has filed a bug one might argue that the question *has* been answered, albeit indirectly. Why does Mathematica do this? Because it has a bug. (As opposed to it being a deliberate design choice).

Comment: Aside from these meta comments, this has been fixed. Should be in the next release.

Comment: @m_goldberg I welcome you to post on Meta if you care.  In this case I see it the same way that Simon's described it.  As a comparison `bugs` questions (of which this is now one) have been *answered* with "confirmed as a but by Wolfram" or "Fixed in 10.0.0" on more than one occasion.  If you post on Meta these should also be addressed.

Comment: @Tali I know you must be busy, but if you are willing could you give or draw some attention to these longstanding bugs/issues?:  [(13347)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13347/121),
[(13349)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13349/121),
[(13399)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13399/121),
[(19656)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19656/121).  The first three are about `Grid`, the last one is about `Graphics`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I've come to agree with Simon Woods. I don't see any reason to raise this in Meta. My suggestion about doing so was prompted by my thinking _you_ might want to raise it there :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard those have nothing much to do with me... you're better off asking someone else.

Comment: @Tali I did not mean to imply that these were in any way your responsibility; I had hoped that you would be able to bring these to the attention of the right person(s).  Anyway, thanks for replying.

Comment: @Tali Are you comfortable with this being tagged as a bug?  (See  Oleksandr's comment under the question above.)  Thanks again for getting this working right either way!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard unless we want to decide how many angels can dance on the head of a pin, let's just call it a bug :)

Comment: @Tali lol -- OK :-)