# Appending and Prepending columns to a dataset in 10.0.2.0

Tags: bugs, dataset

fixed in **10.1** (windows)

---

I just experience a problem in prepending columns to a dataset. I did this a hundred times in 10.0.1.0 - no problems. Now it seems as if it is only possible to append/prepend one column at a time.

```
dataset = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]
```

Then:

```
Prepend[#, "First" -> "one"] & /@ dataset
```

works fine, but

```
Prepend[#, {"First" -> "one", "Second" -> "two"}] & /@ dataset
```

gives an error message:

> ```
> Expression of the form Prepend[SkeletonForm[Struct[{a, b, c},
> {Atom[Integer],  Atom[String], Vector[Atom[Integer], AnyLength]}],
> {weakEval2[First -> one],  weakEval2[Second -> two]}]] cannot be
> evaluated.
> ```

Can anyone give me a hint, if I´m doing wrong (but it worked fine ´til yesterday wen 10.0.2.0 came....)

Comment: It seems like a bug to me since it works on Association expressions and since the error message is weird, but I'll wait for consensus or confirmation before adding the `bugs` tag.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in 10.0.2 that will be fixed in 10.0.3 (if not earlier, and pushed out via a paclet update), but for now you can use this 'indirection' workaround:

```
prepender[x_] := Prepend[x, {"First" -> "one", "Second" -> "two"}];
prepender /@ dataset
```

Comment: How exactly do those paclet updates work and is there a way to tell which sub-sub-version one is running?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't know but check `PacletInformation["Dataset"]`

Comment: Tali, would you give attention to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28998/121) if you have time?  Is this behavior something that could realistically be changed at this time or would it break things?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in **10.1** (windows):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code

```
dataset = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", 
    "c" -> {3}|>, <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>, <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>, <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", 
    "c" -> {}|>}]
Prepend[#, {"First" -> "one", "Second" -> "two"}] & /@ dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Use [Normal](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) to unpack the dataset before prepending:

```
Prepend[#,{"First"->"one","Second"->"two"}]& /@ Normal@dataset // Dataset
```

Comment: I use a similar workaround, but the behavior shown above is buggy, isn´t it?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me but modification of a dataset with Prepend and Append does not seem to be documented.