# prepend a column to grid

Tags: grid-layouts, tableview

How would you prepend a column to a grid? I have seen [Appending and Prepending columns to a dataset in 10.0.2.0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68979/appending-and-prepending-columns-to-a-dataset-in-10-0-2-0)
but that is applied to datasets and I want to retain things as a grid.
I need to prepend an "offset" column to a data set and so far haven't seen any easy way of doing this that retains the grid structure (I've seen a "columns" method but it does not seem to retain the same alignment with the rest of the columns). Could use some help.

*Update*
I'm still having some issues with the solns proposed so let me post the code I am using--maybe I am just asking the wrong question

I'd like to be able to prepend a column that shows the offsets in hex

```
hexdata = ReadByteArray["..<some file>"];
nbytes = Length@hexdata;
addrs = Table[BaseForm[#, 16] &@x, {x, 0, nbytes/16 // Floor}];

hexshowAmount = nbytes/8;
hex = (hexdata[[1 ;; hexshowAmount]] // Normal);

tbl = hex // Partition[#, UpTo@16] &;
nrows = Length@tbl;
ncols = Length@tbl[[1]];

myFunc[val_] := PrimeQ[val]; (* Must Return True or False *)

labels = Flatten@
    Table[If[
      myFunc[tbl[[i]][[j]]], {i, j} -> Hue[RandomReal[], .2, .9], 
      Nothing], {i, nrows}, {j, ncols}] // Quiet;

(* original method *)
outputhex = 
  tbl // Grid[Map[BaseForm[#, 16] &, #, {2}], Frame -> All, 
     Alignment -> Center, Spacings -> Center, 
     Background -> {None, None, labels}, ItemSize -> {2, 2}] &;

(* current method *)
Multicolumn[BaseForm[#, 16] & /@ hex, 16, 
 Appearance -> "Horizontal", Frame -> All, Alignment -> Center, 
 Spacings -> Center, Background -> {None, None, labels}, 
 ItemSize -> {2, 2}]
```

Which results in

[image]

I guess another issue is that I have since found using `Multicolumn` to suit my purpose better. Is there a way to prepend `Multicolumn` that is easier?

*UPDATE2*

Ahh feel like a dummy

```
Join[{Range[5]}, Transpose@#] &@%[[1]] // Transpose // Grid
```

However this will mess up the highlighting so need to change the line

```
labels = Flatten@
    Table[If[
      myFunc[tbl[[i]][[j]]], {i, j } -> Hue[RandomReal[], .2, .9], 
      Nothing], {i, nrows}, {j, ncols}] // Quiet;
```

into

```
labels = Flatten@
    Table[If[
      myFunc[tbl[[i]][[j]]], {i, j+1 } -> Hue[RandomReal[], .2, .9], 
      Nothing], {i, nrows}, {j, ncols}] // Quiet;
```

Hoping there is a less hacky way to accomplish this tho.

Comment: Add a sample grid, simple is fine, as long as it reproduces your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array = Array[a, {4, 5}];

grid = Grid @ array
```

[image]

```
newcolumn = Array[b, 4];

newarray = Transpose[Prepend[newcolumn]@Transpose[array]];

Grid @ newarray
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can  use [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) or [`Join`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html):

```
newarray2 = MapThread[Prepend, {array, newcolumn}];

newarray3 = Join[List /@ newcolumn, array, 2];

newarray == newarray2 == newarray3
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**Update:** If you need to use `grid` and `newcolumn` as inputs, you do

```
newgrid = Grid @ Transpose[Prepend[newcolumn] @ Transpose[First @ grid]]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm having some difficulty getting this to work. I'm thinking it's because you're joining arrays and then converting to a grid?

Comment: @skyfire, please see the update.

Comment: Have been getting an error with concerns over incompatible dimensions. I updated the question with my code so hopefully this helps illustrate my issue better.