# Efficiently test membership for a list of values

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists: `excluded` and `values`. I would like to efficiently determine whether `excluded` and `values` are disjoint. How does one go about doing this (preferably using `FreeQ`)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In version 10.0 you have [`DisjointQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisjointQ.html) (and conversely [`IntersectingQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntersectingQ.html)) to test this. 10.2 adds the `Contains*` family of function with [`ContainsNone`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContainsNone.html) being equivalent to `DisjointQ`. For earlier versions you could build this yourself:

```
ClearAll[disjointQ]
disjointQ[a_List, b_List] := Intersection[a, b] === {}

disjointQ[{1, 2, 3}, {6, 4, 5}]
(* True *)

disjointQ[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 5}]
(* False *)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd expect this might be faster than intersection on larger lists:

```
With[{j = Join[DeleteDuplicates@#1, DeleteDuplicates@#2]}, DeleteDuplicates@j == j] &[l1, l2]
```

Addendum - a little testing, does seem to have advantage when both lists large, otherwise a bit of a wash between this and using intersection... perhaps others can test on non-loungbook environments - I get wildly varying results depending on how I produce the random test lists :-|

Addendum 2: Per comments, differences were from packed/unpacked lists, and in my limited tests the above *is* faster for unpacked... carry on...

Comment: Could you give an example of the wildly varying results?  I presume it's not simply packed vs. unpacked?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: {l1,l2}=Random[...,{2,x}] vs l1=Random[...,x];l2=Random[...,x], for example - I'd imagine is cache related on the hampsterbox...

Comment: And you are running 10.1.0?  (Referring to [Why does list assignment with a packed array result in unpacked values?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28998/121))

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Nope, 10.x still on my voodoo list. And herp-a-derp on my part - could have sworn I checked packing when I got differing results and both cases were unpacked, appears I inadvertently tested same set, so that explains it.

Answer (score 4):

While *highly inefficient* you asked about `FreeQ` and you *could* do this:

```
f0 = FreeQ[#, Alternatives @@ #2] &;
```

More practically here is a condensed version of rasher/ciao's method:

```
f1 = DuplicateFreeQ[Join @@ DeleteDuplicates /@ {##}] &
```

Answer (score 1):

For **short lists** (see comment of Domen) we could use `DeleteElements` or `UniqueElements`

**1.**

`DeleteElements` (new in 13.1)

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {6, 4, 5};

DeleteElements[a, b] == a
```

True

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {6, 1, 5};

DeleteElements[a, b] == a
```

False

**2.**

With `UniqueElements` (also new in 13.1) we can test more than 2 lists

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {6, 4, 5};
c = {9, 8, 7};

UniqueElements[{a, b, c}] == {a, b, c}
```

True

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
b = {6, 4, 5};
c = {9, 2, 7};

UniqueElements[{a, b, c}] == {a, b, c}
```

False

Comment: Note that these two methods are _extremely_ inefficient (significantly slower than `disjointQ` from the accepted answer).

Comment: Thanks, Domen, I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Following @eldo's good observation about `UniqueElements` and grabbing his examples, we can use `Tally` and `MatchQ` as follows:

```
disjointQ[l__List] := MatchQ[Tally[Join[l]][[All, 2]], {1 ..}]

disjointQ[{1, 2, 3}, {6, 4, 5}]

(*True*)

disjointQ[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 5}]

(*False*)

a1 = {1, 2, 3};
b1 = {6, 4, 5};
c1 = {9, 8, 7};

disjointQ[a1, b1, c1]

(*True*)

a2 = {1, 2, 3};
b2 = {6, 4, 5};
c2 = {9, 2, 7};

disjointQ[a2, b2, c2]

(*False*)
```

Comment: Very nice, +1, but couldn't you use `disjointQ[l__List]` for both cases? Making `disjointQ[a_List, b_List] ` redundant?

Comment: Thanks, @eldo! I update my answer :-)