# How to scale the size of Pane to make it fit a Grid element?

Tags: grid-layouts

I am wanting to make a `Pane` scale to fit (if `Spacings` are zero) a `Grid` element.

```
Grid[{{x, x,
   Framed[
    Pane[x,
     ImageSize -> {Scaled[1], Scaled[1]},
     ImageMargins -> 0,
     Alignment -> Center],
    FrameMargins -> 0,
    ImageMargins -> 0], x, x}, {x, x, x, x, x}, {x, x, x, x, x}}, 
 Background -> {None, None, {{1, 3} -> Red}}, ItemSize -> {5, 5},
 Frame -> All,
 Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

Note that I added the `Frame` solely to outline the `Pane` so that the dimensions could be seen.

On my system, OS X 10.6.8, Mma V8.0.4, the scaling works in the x direction but not in the y direction. Can anyone offer an explanation and solution (or could this be a bug)?

[image]

Comment: All these annoying quirks of the 2D layout engine... Also note that none of the cells are actually squares, though item size is 5x5.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I'd completely overlooked that the cells aren't squares!

Answer (score 4):

Quite a long saga but as an FYI this is what I have learned from tech support:

Firstly the documentation for `ItemSize`, under more information, says

> In Grid, w is measured in ems, and h in line heights.

I'd overlooked that. With that information some control should be possible:

```
magicRatio = CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]/CurrentValue["FontLineHeight"];
itemSize = {5, magicRatio*5};

Grid[
 {{x, x, x, x, x}, {x, x, 
   Framed[Pane[x, 
     ImageSize -> 
      Dynamic[itemSize*{CurrentValue["FontMWidth"], 
        CurrentValue["FontLineHeight"]}],
     ImageMargins -> 0,
     FrameMargins -> 0,
     Alignment -> Center],
    FrameMargins -> 0,
    ImageMargins -> 0], x, x}, {x, x, x, x, x}}, 
 Background -> {None, None, {{2, 3} -> Red}}, ItemSize -> itemSize, 
 Frame -> All, Spacings -> {0, 0}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}]
```

On Mac 10.6.8 Mma V8.0.4

[image]

This is close -- may be good enough in most cases -- but no cigar. The problem is that even if this is close enough for someones usage requirements it only works when notebook magnification is set to 100%. For example

125%

[image]

50%

[image]

In theory you would think you could correct for this by getting the magnification

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification] /. Inherited -> 1
```

and you can as long as you don't make the image size `Dynamic` because if you do adding the magnification correction breaks the `Pane` image size:

dynamic image size, magnification 75%

[image]

static image size, magnification 75%

[image]

And an added note/FYI is that the line height is different within a `Dynamic`

[image]

In the end tech support have said that the developers don't see any easy way around this sort of problem.

*see also this* [Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-convert-between-various-itemsize-imagesize-units) though note that even allowing for frame line width I couldn't get the pane to fit precisely in the grid cell.

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment but I want to point out some observations. I don't think, that `Grid` is  the bad guy here. It is the use of `Scaled` in this context where it does not seem to be clear, what exactly it means.

When we use `Scaled` inside a `Graphics`, than the situation seems clear and predictable. We can draw a `Rectangle` exactly from bottom to top, no matter what the specific settings for `PlotRange` are

```
Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[Scaled[{0.4, 0.0}], Scaled[{0.6, 1.0}]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Once we leave this, it is not so clear anymore. We find for instance this example in the help of `Scaled`

> Cell sizes by a fraction of the document width:
>   [image: Mathematica graphics]

But what does this mean for specifying heights in such a setting? We can simply test this

```
Framed[Pane[Null, {Scaled[1], Scaled[1]}]]
```

Here, no matter what I put as value in the second `Scaled`, I always have a frame going over the whole width of the document having the same small height.

I believe, that in `Grid` the behavior is the same. While it is perfectly fine to specify the width with `Scaled`, for the height that does not work.

One possible solution is to use `Grid` only as a layout without specifying the content size and create equally big contents. This is how it is done in most GUI layout managers too: Choose the layout and let the content decide how big it has to be:

```
Grid[
 Table[Framed[Pane["x", ImageSize -> {50, 50}, Alignment -> Center], 
   Background -> ColorData[4, RandomInteger[100]]], {5}, {5}], 
 Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: And in this way we can create true square cells! God bless the lord almighty!

Comment: Note that `Pane[Item[x,ItemSize->{5,5}],ImageSize -> {Scaled[1], Scaled[1]}]` fails as well. To me this is unintuitive. In the x direction the scaling is *not* based on document width but on grid element width. It scales to fill the grid element. Therefore why wouldn't/shouldn't the y axis scaling be based on grid element height? In other words given that it works analogous to `Graphics` in the x direction I don't see why it doesn't in the y direction.

Answer (score 1):

One ugly workaround is to give explicit size values, converted from lineheight to printers points using a system-dependent magic number (just like [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13431/89) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/89)):

```
magic = 8;
item = Framed[Pane[x, ImageSize -> {5, 5}*magic, Alignment -> Center],
    Background -> Pink];
{
 Grid[{{x, x}, {x, x}}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
  ItemSize -> {5, 5},
  Frame -> All, Spacings -> {0, 0}], 
 Grid[{{x, item}, {x, x}}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
  ItemSize -> {5, 5},
  Frame -> All, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
 }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've included the standard grid on the left for comparison so that the magic number is chosen correctly.