# Interactively select a row/column of a Grid

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, grid-layouts

I need a simple way to display tabular data (preferably with `Grid`) and also be able to select a row or column of the table. I've tried different approaches, but I ran into dead ends.

Let's define an example table that contains entries of various types and sizes, and a dynamic variable, `over`, that holds whether the mouse is over a particular row or not (it is easy to extend this approach to inclue setter/toggler controls, or for selecting columns, but that is not the direct aim of this post):

```
data = {
    {11111111, 2, 3}, {4, "55555\n55555\n55555", 6666666.6666},
    {11111111, 2, 3}, {4, "55555\n55555\n55555", 6666666.6666}
};
over = False & /@ data;  (* no row is selected at initialization *)
```

### 1. With multiple `Item`-s

My first approach is the one I thought would work best: treating elements of the grid as `Item`-s, and dynamically update the background of only those entries which are in the given row. It is important to wrap entries individually in `Item[..., Frame -> True]`, so that mouse-movements are captured in the whole cell of the grid and not just where the number is. Unfortunately though when `Item`-s are wrapped in `EventHandler`, `Item`-specific options are lost. Note how frames are missing in the displayed grid on the right:

```
(* simple example showing that Item options are not forwarded by EventHandler *)
{Grid[{{1, 2}, {Item[3, Frame -> True], Item[4, Frame -> True]}}],
 Grid[{{1, 2}, {EventHandler[Item[3, Frame -> True], {}],
                EventHandler[Item[3, Frame -> True], {}]}}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Accordingly, the full row-selector construct fails too, as neither `Frame`, nor `Background` options are evaluated at all. As a consequence, the `EventHandler` is restricted to the numbers only, and not to the full cell of the grid (see the dynamicaly displayed `over`), and no background is updated.

```
Dynamic@over
Grid@MapIndexed[EventHandler[
    Item[#1, Frame -> True, 
     Background -> Dynamic@If[over[[First@#2]], LightBlue, White]],
    {"MouseEntered" :> (over[[First@#2]] = True), 
     "MouseExited" :> (over[[First@#2]] = False)}] &, data, {2}]
```

[image]

### 2. Multiple one-row `Grid`-s

Ok, so if `Item` cannot be used, one has to treat rows as individual objects, for example by assigning same column-sizes for all the rows as individual `Grid`-s. But specifying fixed column sizes is both tedious and prone to break when resized/pagebreaked/etc.

```
Dynamic@over
Column[MapIndexed[EventHandler[
    Grid[{#1}, 
     Background -> Dynamic@If[over[[First@#2]], LightBlue, White], 
     Dividers -> All, ItemSize -> 7],
    {"MouseEntered" :> (over[[First@#2]] = True), 
     "MouseExited" :> (over[[First@#2]] = False)}
    ] &, data],
 Spacings -> {0, -.2}
 ]
```

[image]

Note that I had to use a fixed `ItemSize` value (which cannot be calculated programmatically prior to displaying the `Grid`), and also negative spacing, as the individual row-`Grid`-s are layered on top of each other and alignment is not perfect. This shows when the window is resized or in any way the output is forced to resize in the page. At least now the mouse is captured in the whole row-space.

**Questions**

1. How to create a row/column selector effectively, that retains the economic layout of `Grid`?
2. If this is not possible, can we programmatically get the optimal cell-sizes of a `Grid` to force on multiple one-row `Grid`-s?
3. Is it a bug that `EventHandler[Item[..., opts]]` does not apply `opts` when inside `Grid`? Any workaround?

Comment: IMO avoid `Item` if you intend to use this on large `Grids` -- too much manual messing around -- control things via the `Grid` options; select columns with `EventHandler` in the headers. Looks like @kguler has already dealt with rows.

Comment: @2013 I never intended to use Item *manually* on large grids, as you can see that `MapIndexed` does it for me. Could you please elaborate on your idea about handling headers (especially, when I only want to mouseover rows)? Perhaps even turning it to an answer? For your last sentence: no, I wouldn't say that kguler's answer is a solution. `RowSelector` has problems as well, it wraps items in `Pane` (instead of `Item`) tha causes fixed column sizes and also fails to capture mouse movements when not over the number (as in my first example). See my comment under kguler's answer.

Comment: My comment about using headers was specific for selecting a column -- which is still mentioned in your question title. The comment about item was more of a general comment for anyone actually. I don't know of an *easy* fool proof way of selecting an entire cell. I posted on this a few months ago about my interactions with tech support on this and the upshot was that all methods seem to contain some bug/flaw. this was the tech support interaction: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13713/how-to-scale-the-size-of-pane-to-make-it-fit-a-grid-element Mike (2013 for the new year)

Comment: @2013 Holy god, and I have even commented on that! Obviously I  have a *very* forgetful mind. Thanks for the reminder, Mike!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version 9, there is the new built-in function [`ListPicker`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPicker.html). It can be exploited for tabular data easily:

```
ListPicker[{}, Riffle[
    Thread[Range@Length@data ->
    (Grid[{#}, Dividers -> Center, ItemSize -> {{5, 8, 12}, 2}] & /@ data)],
  Delimiter], 
Spacings -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

I think the first issue is related to the fact that [(docs >> Item >> Possible Issues)](http://wolfram.com/xid/0obhe-fwzfgl)

> "If `Item` is not the top-most item in the child of a function that supports `Item`, it will not work.

So a partial answer for the row selection problem can be obtained by moving `Item` outside `EventHandler` and using `Framed` with `FrameStyle->None` inside the `EventHandler` as follows:

```
 Grid@MapIndexed[
 Item[EventHandler[
   Framed[#1, FrameStyle -> None, 
    Background ->  Dynamic@If[over[[First@#2]], LightBlue,  White]], 
   {"MouseEntered" :> (over[[First@#2]] = True), 
   "MouseExited" :> (over[[First@#2]] = False)}]] &, data, {2}]
```

Update:  Another partial step is perhaps modifying the undocumented **Experimental RowSelector** to accept grid options. As is, it takes only a `List` and  `Dynamic[var]` as inputs and returns the selected row:

```
  Experimental`RowSelector[data, Dynamic[a]]
```

[image]

It may be worthwhile to do some *spelunking* to study the code -- my first impression is that it should not be too difficult to make the necessary modifications to make a version that accepts all `Grid` options.

Comment: Thanks kguler, +1 for `RowSelector` I forgot about!

Comment: Unfortunately, `RowSelector` has some problems as well. By spelunking, I've reconstructed the function, and I can tell you that it works by wrapping entries in `Pane`, so that's why it has fixed column widths (something I don't want to see). Also, if one wraps a `Framed` around this internal `Pane` it becomes obvious, that not each `Pane` fills up the cell completely which causes that sometimes mouse movements are not captured even if inside row but above the actual `Pane` entry.