# How can I set specific ImageSize to each cell of the Grid?

Tags: grid-layouts

I want to make a `Grid` with each cell Imagesize was `{10,10}`.If I place any Gui-Element with more than that cell Imagesize,I don't want to scale that cell.

I want to set each cell ImageSize is `{10,10}`.

For this purpose,I tried with both `Grid` and `GraphicsGrid`.

If you can use `Grpahicsrid`,it's working fine.That corresponding code is in below.

```
GraphicsGrid[ConstantArray["234", {3, 4}], Frame -> All,ImageSize -> {40, 30}]
```

If you use `Grid`,it's not working.That corresponding code is in below.

```
 Grid[ConstantArray["234", {3, 4}], Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {10, 10}]
```

I think,`Itemsize` units totally different compared with `ImageSize`.That's why it's not working .

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a known-difficult problem in this:
[How to convert between various ItemSize/ImageSize units?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/121)

Nevertheless:

[ItemSize:](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ItemSize.html)

> In Grid, w is measured in ems, and h in line heights. In GraphicsGrid, w and h are both measured in absolute printer's points.

[Pane:](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pane.html)

> Pane[expr,{w,h}]
>   makes the pane be w points wide, and h points high, shrinking the contents if necessary.

So we can get close with this:

```
Grid[ConstantArray[Pane["234", {20, 20}], {3, 4}], Frame -> All, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

There is however distortion as the cell sizes become very small:

[image]

I do not know a way around this other than manually adjusting a small negative spacing based on the pane size.